# Not able to import xlsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add a function to export xlsx. Though I am able to export CSV and pdf but **xlsx** is having issues while dynamic import

```
export const exportToXlsx = async (
  gridElement: ReactElement,
  fileName: string
) => {
  const [{ utils, writeFile }, { head, body, foot }] = await Promise.all([
    import('xlsx'),
    getGridContent(gridElement),
  ]);
  const wb = utils.book_new();
  const ws = utils.aoa_to_sheet([...head, ...body, ...foot]);
  utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet 1');
  writeFile(wb, fileName);
}
```

`Cannot find module 'xlsx' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

above is the code and error

Answer (score 0):

I followed the example on YouTube and imported below

import * as XLSX from 'xlsx/xlsx';

This works just fine however it failed to build my TypeScript NextJS project,

Type error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'xlsx/xlsx'. '.../node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/xlsx` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'xlsx/xlsx';`

> 1 | import * as XLSX from 'xlsx/xlsx';

I changed the import to below

import XLSX from 'xlsx';

It built just fine however failed to read the excel, then I followed the previous answer, read through the official documentation

import { read, utils } from 'xlsx';

import read and utils directly from the library and now all is fine

Answer (score -1):

**Solution is in the official documentation. This worked for me** https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: Thanks, @newton but I resolved this issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).